# Can forward declared type templates participate in template specialization ?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

The following does not compile

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// forward declaration of a type template
template<class T, class Alloc = std::allocator<T>> class std::vector; 

template<class T>
struct is_vector : std::false_type { };

// using the forward declared type template
template<class T, class Alloc>
struct is_vector<std::vector<T, Alloc>> : std::true_type { };


#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_vector<std::vector<int>>::value << std::endl;
}
```

I want to make sure that forward declared type templates (above the `vector`) are actually non useable in specialization contexts and that it's not a faulty implementation to blame. Also **why is this happening?** I don't want to create an object of type `vector<>` only use it as a tag to dispatch between specializations; **doesn't inclusion of `<vector>` at the point of instantiation suffice (call site of `is_vector<>`)** ?

Comment: Your forward declaration is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forward-declaring of a standard library container [is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/307408/3959454) (if you manage to compile it), so for `std::vector` you have to `#include <vector>` before defining `is_vector`.

For your own types you can do it though:

```
// forward declaration of a type template
namespace my {
    template<class T, class Alloc> class vector; 
}

template<class T>
struct is_vector : std::false_type { };

// using the forward declared type template
template<class T, class Alloc>
struct is_vector<my::vector<T, Alloc>> : std::true_type { };

namespace my {
    template<class T, class Alloc = std::allocator<T>> class vector {}; 
}
```

Comment: I got a variation of the code in question to compile in VS2012 (it fails in gcc), so got confused about the whole situation. Thnx for the info