# Why is std::regex not a valid type?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, g++, libstdc++

Say I have the following code: 
**class.h**

```
#ifndef CLASS_H
#define CLASS_H

class Class
{
    private:
        std::regex* regex;
};

#endif
```

**class.cpp**

```
#include <regex>
#include "class.h"
// ...
```

Compiling this results in the following error:

```
error: "regex" in namespace "std" does not name a type
    std::regex* regex;
         ^~~~~
```

I am however able to use the std::regex library in any other manner?
Running on GCC 6.1.1. Also tried to compile explicitly with the -std=C++11 flag.

Comment: `#include <regex>` in `class.h`.

Comment: @PeteBecker `basic_regex` is class template, `regex` is not.

Comment: @songyuanyao I cannot believe I missed that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#ifndef CLASS_H
#define CLASS_H

#include <regex>

class Class
{
    private:
        std::regex* regex;
};

#endif
```

Works fine if you actually include the library in your class.

[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7cf346d6c3d4006)

Answer (score 0):

For using a class you have several ways:
The first way is including header file of the class before first usage.
If you do not want to include the header you can use [forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) but in the case of std classes, it can cause an undefined behavior.
Here is an example of using forward declaration for std classes:
[Forward declare an STL container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307343/forward-declare-an-stl-container)