# Forward declaratioin or inheriting std::type_index

Tags: c++, inheritance, stl, forward-declaration

I am working on several pretty heavy modules and I want to provide light-weight header with just some forward declarations. At the same time I am using `std::type_index` within the code in order to switch between different types and thus have to introduce this type in that "forward declarations" header.

For that I have two questions:
1) Is it so bad to make a forward declaration like

```
namespace std { struct type_index; }
```

2) If it is - are there any reasons not to inherit from it, like this:

```
// light.hpp:
struct TypeID;

// heavy_implementation.hpp
struct TypeID : std::type_index {}; // just empty body
```

Finally: if both options are error-prone and/or difficult to support for some reason - is there any way to transparently (without opaque types) introduce `std::` type like `type_index` in light-weight header?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320798/adding-types-to-the-std-namespace) and [the rules for extending `namespace std`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std). You can't do `namespace std { struct type_index; }`.

Comment: And forward-declaring anything from `namespace std` is forbidden - option 1) is right out.

Comment: Why not just include the relevant standard header? It's a standard header.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux most of them are quite heavy (may greatly extend compilation time) coz of numerous templates. But yes it is always possible to just include whatever required. But what if I need to Not do this, are there any ways?

Comment: @Gleb [`<typeindex>`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/type.index#synopsis) has almost nothing it in. But if you insist on not including the header you need to use an opaque type to hide it's use. You cannot forward declare standard types. Related question : [Forward declare a standard container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307343/forward-declare-an-stl-container).

Comment: Note that there is [`<iosfwd>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iosfwd) which forward declares a lot of stream related types but I don't think it will help you in this specific case.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ok, forward declaration is forbidden, but what about inheritance? Also - please, answer in answers, not in comments...