Is it enough to have forward declaration of std::list to test whether a type T is std::list?
For compile time checker which tests whether a type T is std::list I've came up with this template:
#include <list>;

template <typename T>
struct is_std_list: std::false_type
{};

template <typename T, typename Allocator>
struct is_std_list<std::list<T, Allocator>>: std::true_type
{};

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_std_list_v = is_std_list<T>::value;

int main()
{
    static_assert(is_std_list_v<std::list<int>>);
    return 0;
}

And my question is: Is it necessary to have #include <list> or having forward declaration of std::list would be enough? (Because actually I also need to write similar templates for std::vector, std::map, std::set and so on. And I'am afraid if having included all those headers can potentially hit compilation time.):
#include <memory>;

namespace std
{
template <class T, class Allocator = allocator<T>>
class list;
}

template <typename T>
struct is_std_list: std::false_type
{};

template <typename T, typename Allocator>
struct is_std_list<std::list<T, Allocator>>: std::true_type
{};

template <typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_std_list_v = is_std_list<T>::value;

int main()
{
    static_assert(is_std_list_v<std::list<int>>);
    return 0;
}


Yes you would need to include those header(s) if you're using them in any way that require them to be complete. Basically, we pay for what we use.

Forward declaring anything from std is undefined behaviour: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307343/forward-declare-a-standard-container

Technically, forward declaration is enough, but we have no special header with a forward declaration for std::list (std::set, etc.), so you have to include <list>. There is <iosfwd> header for the I/O library, but not for other components.

https://godbolt.org/z/8nfE895Mb so it fails

In addition to not being allowed by the standard, there is also the problem that default parameters can only be declared once. So if the allocator is defaulted in a forward declaration, it cannot be repeated in the "real" declaration. Big problem!


Is it necessary to have #include  or having forward declaration of std::list would be enough?

Yes you would need to include those header(s) if you're using them in any way that require them to be complete. Basically, we pay for what we use.
Baiscally, a forward declaration will work as long as those types need not be complete but if you're using them in a way that require them to be complete then yes, you would need to include the respective headers.
In your example, you're not using the type T in a way that require them to be complete but note that forward declaring a standard container is not allowed.
Also see Forward declare a standard container?

Not sure if it is significant, but std::is_same conspicuously doesn't specify that either type has to be complete in the comments column while all the other traits in the table does : https://eel.is/c++draft/type.traits#tab:meta.rel

In general a forward declaration is enough, but it's not an option for standard classes, because there is no legal way to forward-declare them.
They and namespace std may or may not have compiler-specific annotations attached to them, and you may or may not get into trouble for not duplicating those annotations in your forward declarations.

A better solution here, rather than checking for all the individual containers, is to check for their properties (such as having .begin() and .end() methods). Perhaps std::ranges::input_range is what you want, for example.
